# How to store value of all the checked box to an array and pass it to PHP function using AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am making an Exam-Test Module. In which there will be more than one questions. Each questions has multiple choice answers. I am showing one question at a time. There will be a button called 'Next' till the last question appears. If there are no more questions, the button will say `Submit Test`. When user clicks on `Submit Test` button, all answers of all the questions will be passed to PHP function in the backend to check how many are correct and wrong? I tried doing the following thing but I am getting the array with only one answer and that of first question. How can I achieve this ? I want to store the answers of all the questions in one array and then pass that array to PHP function through AJAX `.post` call or jQuery call ?

**index.php**

```
<div class="modal fade test-modal" id="Test">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <? foreach ($questions as $i=>$question) { ?>
            <div class='question'>
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>QUIZ</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="quest">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <? foreach ($question->getAnsChoice as $answer) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                                <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="<?=$answer->title?>">
                                                <?=$answer->title?> 
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                <? } ?> 
                            </ul>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <p class='error'>Please select an answer</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class='quest_num'><?=$question->number?> of <?=count($questions)?></p>
                    <?  if( count($questions) === 1 ) { ?>
                        <a id="submit_quiz" class="btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Submit Test</a>
                    <? } else if ( count($questions) === $i +1 ) { ?>
                        <a id="submit_quiz" class="btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Submit Test</a>
                    <? }  else { ?>
                        <a class=" btn button btn-lg quiz-btn">Next Question</a>
                    <? } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <? } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('.quiz-btn').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            var checkbox = $(this).parents('.question').children('.modal-body').children('.row').children('.quest').children('ul').children('li').children('.checkbox').children('.icheckbox_square');
            var btn = $(this).parents('.question').children('.modal-footer').children('.quiz-btn')
            var next = false
            var submit = false
            var answers = [];
            $(checkbox).each(function(){
                if ( $(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Next Question' ) {
                    answers.push($('.cb:checked').val());
                    next = true
                } 
                else if ($(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Submit Test') {
                    submit = true
                }
            });

            if ( next ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parents('.question').slideUp(500);
                $(this).parents('.question').next('.question').delay(500).slideDown(500);
            } else if ( submit ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.post('/student/submit_quiz',{asnwers: answers}, function(data){

                });
            } else {
                console.log(next)
                $('.quest .error').fadeIn();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the markup, rather than the templating?

Comment: What example are you asking for ?

Comment: Your markup currently is in the form of php which will generate the actual markup.  I'm asking for an example of generated markup.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with this code that I've noticed:

```
$(checkbox).each(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Next Question' ) {
        answers.push($('.cb:checked').val()); // LOGIC ERROR
        next = true
    } 
    else if ($(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Submit Test') {
        submit = true
    }
});
```

The line of code that I've marked with a comment is querying *the entire document* for all checkboxes matching `'.cb:checked'` with `$('.cb:checked')`. Then, JQuery's `.val()` function gets the value of *just the first element* from that collection.

[Here is the relevant JQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val1):

> **Description:** *Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements.*

So the JavaScript iterates through every checkbox, then repeatedly adds just the first checkbox in the document's value to the array.

To fix this, get the value from the current `this` object:

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('checked') && $(btn).html() == 'Next Question' ) {
    answers.push($(this).val()); // modified line
    next = true
}
```

The second is that the variable `answers` exists separately for each button. You have one button for each section and a new, separate function call for each button. You would need to hoist the `answers` variable outside of the event function:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    var answers = [];
    $('.quiz-btn').click(function(e){
        // Bla bla bla
        answers.push(the_correct_value);
        // Bla bla bla
    });
}
```

If you don't want the `answers` variable to be available to everything in the `document.ready` event listener, you can use a pattern called an Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    (function(){ // Notice how this line starts with an open bracket
        var answers = [];
        $('.quiz-btn').click(function(e){
            // Bla bla bla
            answers.push(the_correct_value);
            // Bla bla bla
        });
    })(); // This line closes the open bracket above, 
          // then immediately runs the result with no arguments

    // the `answers` variable is unavailable in this scope
}
```

The JavaScript that you included was also missing a closing bracket at the very end of the script.

---

All that said, the solution I would use personally would be to wrap the whole thing in a form, use a submit button, listen for the form's `submit` event and just create a JavaScript `FormData` to send the answers:

```
<div class="modal fade test-modal" id="Test">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="/student/submit-quiz" method="POST"><!-- Form tag -->
                <?php foreach($questions as $i => $question): ?>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4>QUIZ</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="quest">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <?php foreach ($question->getAnsChoice as $answer): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input class="cb" type="checkbox" name="answer[]" value="<?= $answer->title ?>" />
                                        <?= $answer->title ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <?php endforeach;  ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p class="quest_num"><?= $question->number ?> of <?= count($questions) ?></p>
                    <?php $last = $question->number === count($questions) - 1; ?>
                    <!-- 
                    Ternary operators, used in these attributes, are like if statements:
                    if the first thing is true, return the second,
                    otherwise return the third.
                    -->
                    <input type="<?= $last ? 'submit' : 'button' ?>" class="btn button btn-lg quiz-btn" value="<?= $last ? 'Submit Test' : 'Next Question' ?>" />
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </form>
            <script>
                /*
                 * Where the real magic happens.
                 */
                $('form[action="/student/submit-quiz"]').on('submit', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    data = new FormData(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        data: data,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(response) {
                            // do something useful with the response
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                    });
                });

                $('form[action="/student/submit-quiz"] input[type="button"]').on('click', function(e) {
                    $(this).parents('.question').slideUp(500);
                    $(this).parents('.question').next('.question').delay(500).slideDown(500);
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```